# Christmas Tree using while in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I can write code for Christmas Tree using for loop. Now, I want to write that code with while loop.  I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
             int i = 0;
             int j =0;
             int k =0;
             while(i<10){
                 while(j<10-i){
                     System.out.print(" ");
                     j++;

                 }
                 while(k<(2*i)+1){
                     System.out.print("*");
                     k++;

                 }
                 ++i;
                 System.out.println("");

             }
}
```

I expect the output of code to be like the christmas tree. But, the actual output is:

```
          *
**
**
**
**
**
**
**
**
**
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723247/creating-a-christmas-tree-using-for-loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a Christmas Tree using for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723247/creating-a-christmas-tree-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the loop indices `j` and `k` into the outer loop, such that they are reset to `0` in each iteration.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
             int i = 0;
             while(i<10){
                 int j = 0;
                 int k = 0;
                 while(j<10-i){
                     System.out.print(" ");
                     j++;
                 }
                 while(k<(2*i)+1){
                     System.out.print("*");
                     k++;
                 }
                 ++i;
                 System.out.println("");
             }
}
```

Then it will print the following tree:

```
          *
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
```